# How can I integrate a VNC client in my app?

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to integrate a VNC client in my app, but the only VNC open-source projects for iPhone I've found have been abandoned since 2008 and are completely out of date...

I also looked for free VNC viewers managing custom URL scheme, so that I can launch a third-party app for the VNC part, but again, no result.

Do you have any idea for integrating a VNC client? Even if it does not really use VNC, I only need to periodically get screenshots of a remote host (under Windows 7).

Thanks...

Comment: Why not try to use the source in your project and when you come across specific issue/problem you can post them on SO.

Comment: tell us please if you are at success..

Comment: Maybe this solution can help resolve your issue ? OnlineVnc integration http://www.onlinevnc.com/support/integration.html

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://virtuallab.tu-freiberg.de/p2p/p2p/vnc/ug/rfbproto.pdf) is the VNC protocol. If you are serious about making a VNC app, read this front to back 10 times. Then use your open-source code you found and you should be able to understand what is happening and why if things go wrong in the implementation.

Comment: OK, I think this is the only solution...So, you should see me again on SO :D

Answer (score 0):

Realizing that this question is a couple of years old... but have found a recent github project that does just this [here.](https://github.com/leonliu/NPDesktop)

Hats off to the developer Leon Liu, looks like a nice job.